# Comparing slices and lifetimes

Tags: rust

I'm trying to update rust-fuse code (which I think compiled on 0.12) to the latest nightly. One of the things that changed is that implicit coercions from `[T]` to `&[T]` were removed. I changed the function calls, but I'm having problem with the following code ([playpen snippet including as_bytes function here](http://is.gd/UqY4yc)):

```
let data: [u8, ..4] = [0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78];
as_bytes(&data, |bytes| {
    assert!(bytes == &[&[0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78]]);
});
```

which throws the following error:

```
src/reply.rs:580:33: 580:57 error: borrowed value does not live long enough
src/reply.rs:580             assert!(bytes == &[&[0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78]]);
                                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<std macros>:1:1: 12:2 note: in expansion of assert!
src/reply.rs:580:13: 580:60 note: expansion site
src/reply.rs:579:33: 581:10 note: reference must be valid for an anonymous lifetime defined on the block at 579:32...
src/reply.rs:579         as_bytes(&data, |bytes| {
src/reply.rs:580             assert!(bytes == &[&[0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78]]);
src/reply.rs:581         });
<std macros>:3:12: 580:58 note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the expression at 3:11
<std macros>:3         if !$cond {
<std macros>:4             panic!(concat!("assertion failed: ", stringify!($cond)))
<std macros>:5         }
<std macros>:6     );
<std macros>:7     ($cond:expr, $($arg:expr),+) => (
<std macros>:8         if !$cond {
               ...
<std macros>:1:1: 12:2 note: in expansion of assert!
src/reply.rs:580:13: 580:60 note: expansion site
```

Questions:

1. Is this the right way to compare the contents of slices?
2. Why does this trigger an error?

For posterity, the latest nightly at the point of writing is `rustc 0.13.0-nightly (81eeec094 2014-11-21 23:16:48 +0000)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User Sharp helped me out on IRC.

I changed the snippet to

```
let data: [u8, ..4] = [0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78];
as_bytes(&data, |bytes| {
    assert_eq!(bytes, [[0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78].as_slice()].as_slice());
});
```

Which compiles and indeed compares the contents of the slices. As to why exactly the error was triggered, I'm still not quite sure.